# i cant update value in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this table to sqlite:

```java
public static final String TABLA_PARA_SEGUIR =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLA_SEGUIR + "(" +
                ID_ELEMENTO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                NOMBRE_MANGA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                URL_MANGA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                URL_IMAGEN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                CONTADOR_CAPITULOS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                BIT_SEGUIR_NO + " INTEGER);";
```

And this is my method to `Update` value:

```java
private ContentValues mapaSiguiendo(SeguirManga sm){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.NOMBRE_MANGA, sm.getNombre());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.URL_MANGA, sm.getUrl());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.URL_IMAGEN, sm.getUrlImagen());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.CONTADOR_CAPITULOS, sm.getContador());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.BIT_SEGUIR_NO, sm.getValorSeguir());
    return cv;
}
```

```
public void actualizar(SeguirManga sm, Context actividad) {
    try{
        this.openWriteableDB();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(PaginasTabla.BIT_SEGUIR_NO, sm.getValorSeguir());
        db.update(PaginasTabla.TABLA_SEGUIR, cv, PaginasTabla.ID_ELEMENTO + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(sm.getId())});
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(actividad, "Modificado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch(Exception sqlException){
        Toast.makeText(actividad, "Error: " + sqlException.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And i add a object variable in my activity:

```
private SeguirManga seguirManga = new SeguirManga();
```

So, in activity I use this to change value using update method:

```java
private void dejarMetodoDaato(){
    PaginasSQL paginasSQL = new PaginasSQL(TMOnlineMangaSeleccion.this);
    seguirManga.setValorSeguir(0);
    paginasSQL.actualizar(seguirManga);
}
```

But this not works because when I press the button:

```java
dejarDato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dejarMetodoDaato();
    }
});
```

Class:

```
public class SeguirManga {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String url;
    private String urlImagen;
    private String contador;
    private int valorSeguir;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getContador() {
        return contador;
    }

    public void setContador(String contador) {
        this.contador = contador;
    }

    public int getValorSeguir() {
        return valorSeguir;
    }

    public void setValorSeguir(int valorSeguir) {
        this.valorSeguir = valorSeguir;
    }

    public String getUrlImagen() {
        return urlImagen;
    }

    public void setUrlImagen(String urlImagen) {
        this.urlImagen = urlImagen;
    }

    public SeguirManga(){}

    public SeguirManga(int id, String nombre, String url, String urlImagen,String contador, int valorSeguir) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.url = url;
        this.urlImagen = urlImagen;
        this.contador = contador;
        this.valorSeguir = valorSeguir;
    }
}
```

Nothing happens because the value is (1) one all the time. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What is `seguirManga`. Where is it defined?

Comment: Is a object class. I'll add in the code question

Comment: *because the value is (1) one all the time* what does this mean? `seguirManga` contains all the values that will update the row in the table, but you only set `seguirManga.setValorSeguir(0);`. What are the values of the other properties of `seguirManga`?

Comment: i dont need update the other properties. just i need update the value that i show in my question

Comment: `mapaSiguiendo()` will set all the columns with values from all the properties of `seguirManga`, so what you are doing is update all the columns.

Comment: ok, i modified my code from actualizar method but not works

Comment: What do you mean by *not works*? Isn't the row updated? Did you check the value of `sm.getId()`? Is it correct?

Comment: Exactly, the row wasn't updated. the value from `sm.getId()`  is 0 and i don't know why

Comment: Then set it to the correct value you want before calling update().

Comment: i don't know how to set the correct value from sm.getId() :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the `id` of the row that you want to update:

```
private void dejarMetodoDaato(){
    PaginasSQL paginasSQL = new PaginasSQL(TMOnlineMangaSeleccion.this);
    seguirManga.setId(5); // change 5 to the value of the id of the row 
    seguirManga.setValorSeguir(0);
    paginasSQL.actualizar(seguirManga);
}
```